# How to convert external DataWindow to SQL Select DataWindow

Tags: powerbuilder

I am trying to make ID badge App. The user design the card after that create table for that card for data entry. So, I create dynamically external DataWindow after accepting the fields from user (column, text, line, picture, checkbox, radiobutton, barcode, ...etc) . Now I need to convert this created DataWindow (on-the-fly) to SQL SELECT DataWindow after I create table for that purpose.

How do I convert ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated mechanism to convert an external datawindow into a SQL Select.  If you know your way around the .srd file format, it can be done manually, but its much easier to recreate a new dw from scratch.

-Paul Horan-
SAP

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is create a new DataWindow with the SQL you want; don't bother tweaking the UI (I'm assuming that's what you want to salvage from the original DW). Take the `table()` portion of the new DW and replace the `table()` portion of the original DW. Be sure you're matching parentheses properly; there are a lot of embedded sets of parentheses within the `table()` portion. If in doubt, use something like NotePad++ to find the matching parentheses for you.

This sounds easy, and that was the easy part. The real kicker, depending on how big the data set is, is to make sure that the data set matches, element for element, data type for data type. Off by one, and you'll have screwed this up in ways that are inconceivably difficult to track down after the fact.

Good luck,

Terry.

---

I missed the "on-the-fly" part the first time through, but the same advice applies; you'll just have to do it programmatically, which is harder still. Finding the matching paren is challenging enough when you don't have to ignore parens that might be contained in the SQL SELECT statement, let alone in other strings like column values expressions. It's possible, just has a lot of edge cases to test that are hard to anticipate, like what happens when a string in the SELECT statement has an opening paren and no closing paren? Then matching data types has to be done programmatically, which in theory means parsing apart the column portions of each DW and comparing the data type. In practice (haven't done this, just tossing up an idea), you could just Create() with both syntaxes and see if a ShareData() between the two fails or not. (ShareData() allows some flexibility, e.g. integer and long, and I have no idea if those differences will cause you problems in other areas that you're trying to do this.) Of course, that might beg the question: Why not just create two sets of DW syntax, one external and one SELECT, and do a ShareData() between them?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it much simpler to create the table first, then create the DataWindow from the SQL. You'll be able to use most of the code you already have to create/modify the visual part of the DataWindow.

I recommend you think very carefully about this design, because sooner or later a user is going to want to make a change to the data on an existing badge design that can't be done without dropping and recreating the table and migrating the data. A good rule of thumb is to *never let the end user design the database.* I would create a table for each data type you are going to support and link them to the badge with an identifer for the attribute. The only thing the user does is add attributes of the available data types, give them names, and stick them on a badge. Keep your external DataWindow and use DataStores for each supported attribute type. If you use the attribute name as your external column name, you can easily write generic code to populate the badge from the attributes on retrieve and copy the attributes back to the DataStores to save. If you will take a look at `pfc_n_cst_dwsrv.of_populatedddw` (the no-parameter version) you will see the basic idea, except you will look at the column's datatype and dispatch a request to the DataStore that handles that data type, giving it the row, and column name (which is the attribute name) to populate. Saving works the same way except you give the DataStore the value to set back to the DataStore. You don't need to worry about whether the data changed, because the DataStore is smart enough to tell if it's the same. If you use PFC you can just set the update list to your DataStores and PFC will take care of them for you (you would use n_ds for the DataStores in this case). You will also need to set the badge id of new rows in the DataStores. You can use the n_ds's `pfc_updatePrep` event for that.